# How do it render a React list where it sequentially goes from a skeleton to the actual data?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, animation, next.js

Introductory Information: I am currently working on a React project that utilizes TypeScript.

In the project at hand, I am implementing a list feature that displays cards. In the absence of data, a list of skeletons is presented to the user. Once the data becomes available, the list transitions to display the actual cards with a sequential effect, gradually changing the opacity from 0 to 1.

However, I aspire to achieve a more refined transition effect. Specifically, during the loading state while the skeleton is visible, upon data fetch, I want each loading skeleton to sequentially transition into its corresponding card, rather than having the skeletons disappear altogether only to be replaced by the list of cards.

The desired transition effect I'm aiming for closely resembles the one observed on the [Airbnb frontpage](https://www.airbnb.com/).

My current implementation resembles the following:

This is the list component:

```
export const ListComponent = ({
  data = [],
}) => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [responsiveHeight, setResponsiveHeight] = useState(0);

  const updateHeight = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const gridItem = ref.current;
      if (gridItem) {
        const gridItemWidth = gridItem.clientWidth;
        const newHeight = (gridItemWidth * 4) / 3.5;
        setResponsiveHeight(newHeight);
      }
    }, 100);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    updateHeight();
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateHeight);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', updateHeight);
    };
  }, []);

  const columns = useMemo(() => {
    if (isSm) return 1;
    if (isLg) return 2;
    return 3;
  }, [isSm, isLg]);

  if (data.length <= 0) return <ListSkeleton />;

  return (
    <Box minHeight={500}>
      <Grid container columnSpacing={3} rowGap={isSm ? 3 : 6} columns={columns}>
        {data.map((item, index) => (
          <StyledGridItem
            key={item.id}
            ref={ref}
            index={index}
            item
            xs={1}
          >
            <Card
              item={item}
              height={responsiveHeight}
            />
          </StyledGridItem>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
};

const fadeIn = keyframes`
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
`;

const StyledGridItem = styled(Grid)<{ index: number }>`
  opacity: 0;
  animation: ${fadeIn} 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation-delay: ${(props) => props.index * 0.075}s;
`;
```

This is the list item component:

```
export const Card = ({
  item,
  height
}) => {
  const router = useRouter();


  return (
    <a href={`/example`} >
      <StyledCard maxHeight={Math.min(height, 464)}>
        <CardImage src={item.image} height={height} />
        <CardDetails item={item}  />
      </StyledCard>
    </a>
  );
};

const StyledCard = styled(Stack)`
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: ${Theme.shadows.medium};

  :hover {
    filter: brightness(95%);
    box-shadow: ${Theme.shadows.large};
  }
`;
```

I have tried to solve this using React-spring without any success - and were thinking that each card probably should display each of their own skeletons.